# PHP upgrade SOAP cant connect to host

Tags: php, soap, upgrade

We recently upgraded our test server from PHP 5.5.* to 5.6.8. I had to fiddle with the php.ini file to get things working again but I cant get my SOAP calls to work properly. The call seems to happen but I get a "can't connect to host" error.

I then copied the contents of the 5.5.* php.ini file and I still get the error. I then reverted back to the old version and the SOAP works again. I tried replacing the soap DLL from 5.5.* with 5.6.8 and that totally broke.

Ive triple checked my php.ini SOAP settings and everything is perfect. Im at a total loss as to what is causing this problem? Is it possible there is another dependancy that is needed in 5.6.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above was the SSL certificate. We are working on a staging environment on HTTPS but the certificate is not valid. With PHP 5.6+ if the certificate is invalid the SOAP call throws an exception.